# Terraform azurerm_virtual_machine_extension error "extension operations are disallowed"

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, terraform, powershell-remoting, azure-rm

I have written a Terraform template that creates an Azure Windows VM. I need to configure the VM to Enable PowerShell Remoting for the release pipeline to be able to execute Powershell scripts. After the VM is created I can RDP to the VM and do everything I need to do to enable Powershell remoting, however, it would be ideal if I could script all of that so it could be executed in a Release pipeline.  There are two things that prevent that.

The first, and the topic of this question is, that I have to run "WinRM quickconfig". I have the template working such that when I do RDP to the VM, after creation, that when I run "WinRM quickconfig" I receive the following responses:

```
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is not set up to allow remote access to this machine for management.
The following changes must be made:

Configure LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to grant administrative rights remotely to local users.

Make these changes [y/n]?
```

I want to configure the VM in Terraform so LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy is set and it becomes unnecessary to RDP to the VM to run "WinRM quickconfig". After some research it appeared I might be able to do that using the resource azure_virtual_machine_extension.  I add this to my template:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmx" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  location             = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name  = "${var.vm-resource-group-name}"
  virtual_machine_name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.name}"
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                 = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version = "2.0"

settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
          # "commandToExecute": "powershell Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System' -Name 'LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy' -Value 1 -Force"
    }
SETTINGS
}
```

When I apply this, I get the error:

```
Error: compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> Code="OperationNotAllowed" Message="This operation cannot be performed when extension operations are disallowed. To allow, please ensure VM Agent is installed on the VM and the osProfile.allowExtensionOperations property is true."
```

I couldn't find any Terraform documentation that addresses how to set the allowExtensionOperations property to true. On a whim, I tried adding the property "allow_extension_operations" to the os_profile block in the azurerm_virtual_machine resource but it is rejected as an invalid property. I also tried adding it to the os_profile_windows_config block and isn't valid there either.

I found a statement on Microsoft's documentation regarding the osProfile.allowExtensionOperations property that says:

> "This may only be set to False when no extensions are present on the virtual machine."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.osprofile.allowextensionoperations?view=azure-dotnet

This implies to me that the property is True by default but it doesn't actually say that and it certainly isn't acting like that.  Is there a way in Terraform to set osProfile.alowExtensionOperations to true?

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue adding extensions using Terraform, i created a Windows 2016 custom image,

provider "azurerm" version ="2.0.0"
Terraform 0.12.24

```
Terraform apply error: 
compute.VirtualMachineExtensionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 
-- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. 
Status=<nil> 
Code="OperationNotAllowed" 
Message="This operation cannot be performed when extension operations are disallowed. To allow, please ensure VM Agent is installed on the VM and the osProfile.allowExtensionOperations property is true."
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same error, possible solution depends on 2 things here.
You have to pass provider "azurerm" version ="2.5.0 and you have to pass os_profile_windows_config (see below) parameter in virtual machine resource as well. So, that terraform will consider the extensions that your are passing. This fixed my errors.

```
 os_profile_windows_config {
provision_vm_agent = true
}
```